# How to add a surfaceview into a fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, surfaceview

I have a surface view and a fragment, I need to display my surface view in that fragment. Below are my surface view and fragment classes.

Is the approach I'm doing right, to draw in a fragment? Or do you have any other suggestion?

Fragment class:

```
public class fragment1 extends Fragment{
public static int width,height;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup   container,Bundle savedInstanceState){

            return new GameView(getActivity());
}
```

Fragment xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/index"
android:orientation="vertical" >


</LinearLayout>
```

gameview(Surface View)

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView {

private Bitmap bmp;

private SurfaceHolder holder;



public GameView(Context context) {

      super(context);

      holder = getHolder();

      holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

             @Override

             public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

             }


             @Override

             public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

                    Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas(null);

                    onDraw(c);

                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);

             }



             @Override

             public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,

                           int width, int height) {

             }

      });

      bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),                    R.drawable.rec01);

}


@Override

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

      canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

      canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 10, 10, null);

}
```

}

Comment: I use onDraw(..) in a view that extends View without problems. I mean, without defining a surfaceHolder. Using a surfaceholder may be safer, I don't know.

Comment: based on your comment i tried to add a view class rather than surface view , works like charm... but dont know the problem with surface view!